# Change expected delivery date

Tags: php, date

I display the expected delivery date on our products, using the following line:

```
<?php if (in_array($_product->getData('delivery_eta'), array('2010-01-01 00:00:00','12-31-2099'))):?>
```

I want to expand this, by adding another if element that checks the currect date and if it **"delivery_eta"** is lower than today.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like:

```
<?php
$productEta = $_product->getData('delivery_eta');
if(strtotime($productEta) < strtotime(date("d-m-Y"))) {
   //Your code for if eta is less than today
}
?>
```

Comment: That does not seem to work. When I check the value of `date` that you suggest. I get the following value 1480377600

Comment: yes that is the timestamp, I'm assuming getData('delivery_eta') is a date value like 20/11/2016 so we need a timestamp value to compare to todays timestamp. So we do `strtotime` to create the comparable timestamp.